# Change Organiser for Outlook calendar Event in Node.js

Tags: node.js, calendar, outlook-restapi, office365-restapi

How to programmatically change organiser of outlook calendar event?
 I have created one calendar event with two attendees using Outlook Rest API so I want to make as a organiser to one of the attendees.

Anyone have idea on this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the organizer after an event has been created isn't supported.  You have to cancel the original meeting and send a new one with the right organizer.  This isn't an API limitation, this is true for Outlook as well.

Comment: Hi Venkat ,Thank you for your reply.while sending or creating a new one after cancelling I need to use Is-organiser=false field  to make as organiser to another attendee right?

Comment: No, assuming you are using code flow to get an OAuth token, the signed-in user is the organizer.  There isn't a way for you to make one of the other attendees the organizer.

Comment: If I want to make new organiser for only  one instance event among the recurring event,how to do this?
Example: I have created one recurring event like Every Monday with 3 instances so how to make new organiser for any one of the instance?